# NFC NDEF message

Tags: android, nfc

i am trying populate my password field on my computer via a android application using NFC. i have a samsung galaxy sIII and a ACR122U USB NFC read/writer.
I have read a number of guides but i have not found them very helpful (i am new to this) this is all iv got so far, if anyone could advices a good guide to help or show me how to do this it would be greate help

I have ensured that my AndroidManifest is completed 
(please note in this I am saying the password i wish to send is Password)

```
public class NFCHandler extends Activity {
private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
private TextView mText;
private NdefMessage mMessage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);

    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    // Create an NDEF message a URL
    mMessage = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", "Password".getBytes()));

    setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_list_item);
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.setNdefPushMessage(mMessage, this);
        mText.setText("Password");
    } else {
        mText.setText("This phone is not NFC enabled.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to ask here? How to send an NDEF message from the phone to the ACR122U? How to receive the password on the PC sinde and fill it into the password field?

Comment: Both Michael, the guides that I have seen dont rely talk about the pc side, and i am struggling with the phone application.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send the password in the ndef record. Your code is currently setting the password on the mText field which has no relation to the NdefRecord you created. Instead of using NdefRecord.createUri you should use NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", "password".getBytes("UTF-8")) if that is what you wish to send to the NFC reader.